# Embedding figure into PyQT5 GUI using python matplotlib plt.subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

Here I have PyQT5 GUI with group box, try to embeds a figure with multiple subplot.
From stackflow website, I got a good example with annotate to show desired information on it successfully.

Now, I try to put the figure into GUI group box.
I use "self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)" and "self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(321)", I could see a plot successfully been added into GUI groupbox.

As annotate example I mentioned above, it could show in individual figure plot
"fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,1,figsize=(16,9), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2,1,1,1]}, sharex=True)"

Therefore, how can I put annotate example into GUI groupbox using plt.subplots instead of add_subplot?
[Annotation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt0vM.jpg)